# How do I make every Monday Bold in the monthCalendar control?

Tags: c#, winforms, monthcalendar

I am developing an application. I initially wanted to allow the user to ONLY select a Monday. After spending a considerable amount of time, I found out that that wont be possible unless i create my own control.

Therefore i wanted to know how do I make Monday's Bold (and even change the background color) so it's more noticeable?

Is there a way to programatically select a Monday (of the same week) no matter what day is selected on the week?

For example, if they click 2/16, that 2/13 would automatically be selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done this on a datetime picker value changed event. 
Seems to work. Hope it helps!

```
  private void dtP1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var days = DayOfWeek.Monday - dtP1.Value.DayOfWeek;

            if (dtP1.Value.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Monday)
            {
                dtP1.Value = new DateTime(dtP1.Value.Year, dtP1.Value.Month, dtP1.Value.Day + days);
            }

        }
```

I've managed to write and extension method for it.

```
 public static class DateTimeHelper
    {
        public static void AlwaysChooseMonday(this DateTimePicker dtp, DateTime value)
        {
            var days = DayOfWeek.Monday - dtp.Value.DayOfWeek;

            if (dtp.Value.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Monday)
            {
                dtp.Value = new DateTime(dtp.Value.Year, dtp.Value.Month, dtp.Value.Day + days);
            }
        }
    }
```

Then the value changed event just becomes

```
 private void dtp1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             dtP1.AlwaysChooseMonday(dtP1.Value);
        }
```

a lot neater.

Comment: Thanks. I am using monthCalendar and there is no event for ValueChanged. I will see what the equivalent event is. Oddly this fails when you select a date whose monday occurs in the previous month (I selected 2/3/17 and boom crash)